# Which framework for android development uses nodejs and embeds it in apk?

Tags: android, node.js

I have need to run certain node modules on android system inside my android application.
I have spent some time on internet, but could not find definitive answer:

Which framework for android development uses nodejs and embeds it in apk?

Thank you

Comment: What modules? Check "run ja on Android".

Comment: @MarianPaździoch Ideally i want to have fully functional nodejs inside my app. I understand that many modules will not run simply because they are not written for android system, but that's okay.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch Oh and i mean npm modules.